# Unequal horizontal adjustment to title lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a plot with a fairly wide y-axis label, so I want to adjust the title to the left so that it's flush with the label rather than the axis (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401111/left-adjust-title-in-ggplot2-or-absolute-position-for-ggtitle)) but the twist is that I have a multiline title. I've been using hjust, but it adjusts the two lines differently. 
For example

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Figure: My long and winding title\nthat goes on and on and on") +
  ylab("My long label") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, hjust=-.33, color="black", face="bold")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))
```

Gives
[image: plot output]
Is there a way to make the start of the two lines of the title flush after adjusting them horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code. First create the plot and assign it to `g`, then turn `g` in to a `grob` with `ggplotGrob`. Consequently, manipulate the title left alignment in the `layout` part of the grob (from 5 to 2). And Finally plot the adapted grob.

```
g <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Figure: My long and winding title\nthat goes on and on and on") + 
  ylab("My long label") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16,  color="black", face="bold"))  + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))


grob <- ggplotGrob(g)

# what is the current content
grob$layout$l[grob$layout$name == "title"]
[1] 5

grob$layout$l[grob$layout$name == "title"] <- 2

# plot the new grob
grid::grid.draw(grob)
```

yielding this plot:

[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: I think this is the best/cleanest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question.

I think you're just missing a space in the title.

`ggtitle("Figure: My long and winding title\n that goes on and on and on")`

[image: figure]

Comment: I already have a plot.title in theme with hjust. This new one just overrides it. If I set it to the original -.33 I get the same issue

Comment: Sorry why do you want it to be -0.33? Is the output above incorrect? Do you want the title to be to the left of the y-axis?

Comment: Yes, "I want to adjust the title to the left so that it's flush with the label rather than the axis"

Answer (score 0):

`hjust` is the responsible of the white space.
 Removing it remove the 2 white spaces on the second line.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Figure: My long and winding title\nthat goes on and on and on") +
  ylab("My long label") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, 
                                  color="black", face="bold",
                                  ),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

If you want to **automatically split the title in multiple line**, you can use `gsub`. Here is one example where I split the title after 30 characters. [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484909/10041823)

```
long_title <- "Figure: My long and winding title that goes on and on and on"

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle(gsub('(.{1,30})(\\s|$)', '\\1\n', long_title)) +
  ylab("My long label") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, 
                                  color="black", face="bold",
                                  ),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Hope that help !

Comment: But I want to horizontally adjust the title. Just both lines equally.

Comment: @pgcudahy Sorry for the misunderstanding. The EDIT1 splits the long title according a number of character per line (here 30).

Answer (score 0):

Here You have it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library("gridExtra")
p<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle("") +
  ylab("My long label") +
  theme_bw() +theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))


title.grob <- textGrob(
  label = "Figure: My long and winding title\nthat goes on and on and on",
  x = unit(0, "lines"), 
  y = unit(0, "lines"),
  hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
  gp = gpar(fontsize = 16))
p1 <- arrangeGrob(p, top = title.grob)
grid.draw(p1)`
```

[image]