# How to align a multiline title

Tags: r, ggplot2, title

I have a problem with `ggplot` title positioning. When I use `hjust` argument to slide title a bit right, both lines undesirably slide left and right. I want them one under the other. `drawlabel()`,`annototations` are not useful for my case, because they depend on x and y axis and their units(date,currency,kg) which mean every time I have to adjust them. I want unique coordinate system, whatever I am plotting I can easily use same place for different plots.

An undesired example with code is shown below.

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=round(rnorm(10)*1:10,2))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
 geom_line(size=0.75)+
 labs(title = 'Here comes my title like that some words\nand my second line title')+
 theme(
   plot.title.position = 'plot',
   plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.075)
 )
```

**Undesirable plot**

[image]

**Desirable plot**

[image]

Comment: possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662815/unequal-horizontal-adjustment-to-title-lines-in-ggplot

Comment: I also took a glance at the link you provided. I do not think they refer to my problem.
Here I want to slide both lines a bit right, both of them lose their starting point. But  solutions in the link only refer to fixed default title place.

Comment: After having a look at the issue I don't think that this is possible using default ggplot options. If you want both lines left aligned (one under the other) you have to use `hjust=0`. For the positioning ggplot only offers the two options `plot` and `panel` (I tried to adjust the margin but this only allows for adjusting top and bottom margins, while left and right have no effect). See also https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3252 for a discussion of this issue.

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523389/ggplot2-multiline-title-different-indentations?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You might find some workarounds with `cowplot`. I posted a question a while ago that might help in going that route https://stackoverflow.com/q/50973713/5325862

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @stefan in the comments that there appears to be no way to do this with `theme`.

One hackish approach is to remove your `hjust` change and manually move the position of the title by editing the grid layout.

```
library(ggplot)
library(grid)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(size=0.75) +
  labs(title = 'Here comes my title like that some words\nand my second line title') +
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot')
grob <- ggplotGrob(p)
grob$layout[grob$layout$name == "title","l"] <- 4.5
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(grob)
```

[image]

You can change `4.5` as necessary for the desired effect.

Comment: I actually found this solution, however problem here is that when you change **4.5** argument to for example 4 or 2 or 5.5 it does not change as expected. Only changes to particular places. I do not know how can I add image on comment.

Comment: @badalovi; if you look at the `l`eft column of `grob$layout` you wil get an idea of what value to use i.e. using `3` would align it with the y-axis label is perhaps sensible, or the panel use `5` etc

Answer (score 5):

[`ggtext`](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) provides tools that make it a bit easier to muck about with text. In the example below, using the `<br>` to add a newline we can then render this with the theme parameter `element_textbox_simple` (with a little padding around the text).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=round(rnorm(10)*1:10,2))

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
 geom_line(size=0.75)+
 labs(title = 'Here comes my title like that some words <br> and my second line title') +
 theme(
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_textbox_simple(padding = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5))
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution you provide. 
This is one of the straightforward approaches. But if I am not mistaken it depends on margins or fixes margins. Which means that I can not change margins for another reason, right?

Comment: @badalovi; `element_textbox_simple` takes a margin argument if you want to manually change things.Ian's answer provides  a way to align the title with the other grobs using the indices in the gtable which you may find  easier but if you additionally want to format individual words / sections of words (i.e. colour / bold / underline etc) then this answer will make things a bit easier.

Comment: I see your point @user20650. Thank you for your attention and for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I might miss the obvious, but a simple option is to use a *subtitle* :)

Now, the indentation with hjust with title and subtitle is also NOT the same, however, it seems to be a *constant*! Weirdly this is totally dependent on your device. For example, in my RStudio Viewer, I need a constant of ~2.1, for ggsave ~1.49, and with reprex, I need 1.525 (see the example). However, once found the constant, it is actually fairly consistent.
At least - for me here.

**Works also for negative hjust!**

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = round(rnorm(10) * 1:10, 2))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  labs(
    title = "Here comes my title like that some words",
    subtitle = "and my second line title"
  )

hjusttitle <- 0.175

p +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = hjusttitle, size = 14),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = hjusttitle / 1.525, size = 14)
  )
```

[image]

```r
hjusttitle <- -0.15

p +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = hjusttitle, size = 14),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = hjusttitle / 1.525, size = 14)
  )
```

[image]

```r
hjusttitle <- 1

p +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = hjusttitle, size = 14),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = hjusttitle / 1.525, size = 14)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This looks pretty straight-forward solution. Thank you. I do not want to be shown a person does not like anything, however this also limits you using subtitle as far as I know ggplot2 allows you to use only one title and one subtitle.